# How can i be sure to trap all exceptions

Tags: botframework

I am unable to debug my bot due to corporate firewalls so i am left with deploying and testing in Azure.

I keep getting the default unhandled exception message and usually I do not know why without a lot of trial and error.

How can i be sure to trap all exceptions so that i can log the error?

For example this display the choice list fine but then sinks without a trace before the user gets a chance to choose and option. I have catches in both the calling function and the ResumeAfter, neither of which get invoked:

```
PromptDialog.Choice<int>(
    context,
    OnSelectedPolicy,
    options,
    "Which policy do you want to claim under?",
    "Ooops, that is not a valid option, please try again",
    3,
    PromptStyle.Auto);
```

Answer (score 0):

Register an exception handler in your startup code. We use log4net so we have a line like this in `Application_Start`:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger), 
                                               new Log4netExceptionLogger());
```

With a supporting class which shows how to process the error:

```
public class Log4netExceptionLogger : ExceptionLogger {
    private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger("MSBot Unhandled Exception");

    public override void Log(ExceptionLoggerContext context) {
        log.Error(context.Exception);
    }
}
```